# programmatically put the calling servlet into the action of an HTML Form

Tags: jsp, servlets

in a controller servlet I have the doGet as

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
  RequestDispatcher view = req.getRequestDispatcher("views/insert_item.jsp");
  view.forward(req, res);
}
```

in the view `insert_item.jsp` I want to `post` back to the same calling servlet but in the HTML Form of the insert_item.jsp I want to specify the Action programmatically such as

```
<form method="post" action="<%= request.GET_CALLING_SERVLET%>">
```

I've tried

```
<form method="post" action="<%= request.getServletPath() %>">
<form method="post" action="<%=request.getRequestURI %>">
```

but these just put the path to the view `views/insert_item.jsp`

Is it possible to programmatically put the calling servlet into the action of an HTML Form??
Or am I once again trying some unorthodix approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always pass the original request in an attribute.

But a simpler way would be to use an empty action attribute (html).

```
<form method="post" action="">
```

Comment: I had tried that but it didn't work.  But now I realize why.  I was calling the servlet as http://localhost:8080/TestServlet2?method=new.  When I hovered over the submit button, it was keeping the url parameters of "new" and that was overriding my hidden form paramter that set method=sqlInsert